# Django - No module named C:\Users\<old deleted django project path>\settings

Tags: python, django

I have created a virtual environment and then installed Django & created a project "DjangoWeb" using below cmd in my virtual space "virenv_1".

```
django-admin startproject DjangoWeb
```

My directory structure is as follow:

```
main_dir/
├── virenv_1/
└── DjangoWeb/   
    ├── manage.py
    └── DjangoWeb/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

When I run the django server using the below cmd in my virtual space, I get an unusual error as shown in the screenshot.

```
(virenv_1) C:\Users\..\main_dir\DjangoWeb>python manage.py runserver
```

Error screenshot:
[image]

The path to 'settings' file shown in error is of an old project I had created earlier and which no more exists now.

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem.

So the file **wsgi.py** sets an Environmental Variable **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** each time you create a DJANGO project.

In my case, this variable was set while creating the first project djangoTut and it was not being overwritten on creating my new project DjangoWeb.

I simply deleted the existing entry in System Properties -> Environmental Variables and the problem was resolved.

Once you update the Environmental Variables, don't forget to restart your command prompt.